# Oracle SQL - Delete Entries Based Off Unique Rows

Tags: sql, oracle

I am pulling a single column from a DB and it looks something like this:

```
Group
A
A
A
B
B
B
C
D
D
D
E
F
F
F
```

I need to delete unique entries, so entries A, B, D and F should stay and entries C and E should be deleted.

I am getting this row based of a query like this:

```
select Group from table where type = 'rec';
```

and basically each type should have more than one group and if it doesn't it needs to be removed.

NOTE: I need it to be automated and not just a "remove C" and "remove E" because there are thousands of rows and I'm not sure which I will need to delete unless I just find them. The number of rows that will need to be deleted will also be changing, hence why I need it to be automated based off of count.

Comment: basically you want all unique chars in string be removed?

Comment: I want to remove the groups that only occur once. Each group needs multiple entries to function, so any group that only appears once from my select statement needs to be removed.

Comment: Do you need to actually remove them from the underlying table, or do you just need them to not appear in your `SELECT` statement?

Answer (score 2):

One method is:

```
delete t
    where "group" in (select "group" from t group by "group" having count(*) = 1);
```

Based on your sample code:

```
delete t
    where type = 'rec' and
          "group" in (select "group" from t where type = 'rec' group by "group" having count(*) = 1);
```

You could also do this as:

```
delete t
    where type = 'rec' and
          not exists (select 1
                      from t t2
                      where t2.group = t.group and t2.type = 'rec' and t2.rowid <> t.rowid
                     );
```

Answer (score 0):

Judging by your comments all you need is running total. If entry occurred once then select/delete it. The analytic functions is the best and easiest way if you ask me:

```
SELECT * FROM 
(
 SELECT COUNT(grp) OVER (PARTITION BY grp ORDER BY grp) cnt -- number of occurances --
       , grp 
   FROM
   ( -- convert to multi-row - REPLACE AAABBB with your actual column --
    SELECT trim(regexp_substr('A A A B B B C D D D E F F F', '[^ ]+', 1, LEVEL)) grp
      FROM dual -- from your table_name --
    CONNECT BY LEVEL <= regexp_count('A A A B B B C D D D E F F F', '[^ ]+')
   )
  )
 WHERE cnt = 1 -- Select/Delete only those that appeared once -- 
 /
```

Output:

```
cnt|grp
--------
1   C
1   E
```

Full output, if you comment where:

```
cnt|grp
--------
3   A
3   A
3   A
3   B
3   B
3   B
1   C
3   D
3   D
3   D
1   E
3   F
3   F
3   F
```

Final edit based on your questions. This simulates your table:

```
WITH your_table AS
(
 SELECT 'rec' grp_type FROM dual
 UNION ALL
 SELECT 'not_rec' grp_type FROM dual
 )
 SELECT grp_type FROM your_table WHERE grp_type = 'rec' -- apply all that above to this select --
 /
```

Comment: Is there a way to effectively replace the 'A A A B B B C D D D...' string in the query with the select statement? I tried to just replace and it didn't work

Comment: @M. Rogers - if your question addressed to me then I'm not sure I understand what you meant. Example?

Comment: it was. The output of A A A B B B C D D... is the result of "select Group from table where type = 'rec';" is there a way to replace the string of A A A B B C D D with the string? I tried to just replace it but it broke functionality

Comment: @M. Rogers - the string means to put quotes around the output? Is this what you need - 'A A A B B B C D D...'?

Comment: How can I do something like this:

SELECT trim(regexp_substr(select Group from table where type = 'rec';, '[^ ]+', 1, LEVEL)) str
     FROM dual
   CONNECT BY LEVEL <= regexp_count(select Group from table where type = 'rec';, '[^ ]+')

Comment: @M. Rogers - Replace A A A B B B C D D D E F F F in my example with SELECT group... Copy, paste and replace letters with actual column in your query. That's all. My 'str' is your group

Comment: @@M. Rogers - I renamed my alias to grp for group as group is a key word, this is why grp. Also, I added comments. All you have to do is replace letters with your actual column name, e.g.  
SELECT trim(regexp_substr(group, '[^ ]+', 1, LEVEL)) group  FROM your table CONNECT BY... I'm doing this not for score just to help.